# Rolle’s theorem defined different ways

Tags: calculus

Howard Anton’s Calculus Early Transcendentals defines Rolle’s Theorem as :

1 $f$ cont on the closed interval [a,b]

2 $ f $ differentiable on (a,b)

3 $f(a)=0 $ and $f(b)=0,$ then....

Stewart defines this theorem with #3 being $f(a)=f(b)$

Seems like a BIG difference!

Everything I see on the internet says $f(a)=f(b)$, NOT the more stringent requirement of $f(a)= f(b)=0.$

Thoughts?

Comment: These formulations are equivalent (yes, $f(a)=f(b)=0$ implies the more general one). The equals to $0$ is there to emphasize that between two roots of $f$, there's a root of $f'$. I remember seeing this addressed on MSE.

Comment: I don’t see how they are equivalent. In one version if $f(2)=6$ and $f(5)=6$, then I could apply the theorem, and in Anton’s book I could NOT..

Comment: it's here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872218/rolles-theorem-whats-the-right-statement-of-the-theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the typical way of stating Rolle's Theorem has its third condition as $f(a)=f(b)$ and doesn't require them to be zero.

However, if you were to try and *prove* Rolle's theorem, you could prove the version where $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and then argue that if you only know $f(a)=f(b)=N$, look at $g(x)=f(x)-N$. Then $g(a)=g(b)=0$ and it is still continuous and differentiable in the right places. So you can apply that version of Rolle's Theorem to conclude $g'(x)=0$ somewhere on the interval, and since $f'(x)=g'(x)$, you also know $f'(x)=0$.

You can also use this move to apply Rolle's theorem in other cases. Like in your comment where $f(2)=f(5)=6$, apply Rolle's Theorem to $f(x)-6$.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider the 'auxiliary function' $ g(x) = f(x) - c $, where $ c = f(a) = f(b) $, noticing it's also continuous and differentiable on the pertinent domains